# What is the pythonic way to get the next unprocessed list column?

Tags: python, list

I'm doing the following, and it works, but it is not elegant. I'm wondering if anyone has any insight as to a prettier way to do this.

Let's say I have n booleans that the user will set to be true or false. For each boolean, there is an associated function do_something that takes as input the next unprocessed column in a multidimensional list called myList. The following code does just this:

```
i=0
if boolean1:
    do_something1([a[i] for a in myList])
    i+=1
if boolean2:
    do_something2([a[i] for a in myList])
    i+=1
if boolean3:
    do_something3([a[i] for a in myList])
    i+=1
...
```

Even though it works, something in me tells me that there is a much more elegant way to do it. It seems like it might be better to push the columns onto a queue and then pop them off when one of the booleans is satisfied. But that seems like a whole lot of overhead. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you store the data as a list of columns rather than a list of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put the booleans and functions into a list, you could do:

```
processing = zip(booleans, functions)

for i, action in enumerate([p for (b,p) in processing if b]):
    action([a[i] for a in myList])
```

Answer (score 1):

Transpose `myList` first (flip rows into columns) and then iterate over it.

```
for boolean, row in zip(booleans, zip(*myList)):
    if boolean:
        process(row)
```

The inner `zip` is part of the idiom `zip(*l)`, which transposes a list.

Comment: for `booleans = [True, False, True]`, wouldn't that just process columns 0 and 2?

Comment: Not according to the OP, the counter is only incremented on `True`

Comment: Thomas Fenzi is correct. However, I am upvoting you because your answer is useful: you have enlightened me about the magic of zip(*l).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
processing = ((boolean1, do_something1), (boolean2, do_something2), 
              (boolean3, do_something3))
i=0
for b, process in processing:
    if b:
        process[(a[i] for a in myList])
        i+=1
```